# How can I do some action when one specific Tab is selected using Javafx

Tags: javafx-2, javafx

I'm trying to do something when one tab of my tabPane is clicked, I've tried use Action Event but it doesn't work:

```
public void tabPressClicked (ActionEvent event){
        comboBoxPresYear.setVisible(true);
        lblPresYear.setVisible(true);
    }
```

**[EDITED]**

The right way to do that:

```
tabPresentation.setOnSelectionChanged(new EventHandler<Event>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(Event t) {
                if (tabPresentation.isSelected()) {
                    comboBoxPresYear.setVisible(true);
                    lblPresYear.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do/ what ActionEvent you are expecting but try either something like:

```
tabPane.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
        // do something...
    }
});
```

if you want to do something when the selection changes (any tab)

or try:

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Tab.html#setOnSelectionChanged%28javafx.event.EventHandler%29

for a specific tab (I haven't tried this yet, though).

Comment: What I need is when I select a specific tab (tabPress) set one comboBox and one label Visible, just it

Comment: just add if(newValue = yourSpecificTabNUmber) { comboBoxPresYear.setVisible(true);
        lblPresYear.setVisible(true);}  to changed method :)

Comment: Did you try Tab.setOnSelectionChanged I mentioned?

Answer (score 13):

You do that with the `selectedItemProperty` or `selectedIndexProperty` like Puce was saying. Here the solution with the `selectedItemProperty` which I think is better because you get the selected `Tab` item itself

```
tabPane.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Tab>() {

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Tab> observable, Tab oldTab, Tab newTab) {
        if(newTab == tabPresentation) {
            comboBoxPresYear.setVisible(true);
            lblPresYear.setVisible(true);}
        }
    });
```

I assume the `tabPresentation` is the `Tab` object itself.

Comment: This is really nice, because I get the tab item directly and don't need to refer to a specific tab number, which might change.

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't this be the easiest way to do it

```
    tab.selectedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (newValue) {
            comboBoxPresYear.setVisible(true);
            lblPresYear.setVisible(true);}
        }
    });
```

Comment: That's a great JavaFX8 solution

Answer (score 0):

import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;

```
    tab1.setOnSelectionChanged((EventHandler<Event>) t -> {
        if (tab1.isSelected()) {
            System.out.println(tab1.getText() + " is selected");
        }
    });
```